# Make included layout occupy top 30% of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've tried this in *layout/layout_30*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_that_occupies_30"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works. The top 30% of screen turn black. The thing is, when I try to **include** this layout in another layout (let's say *main_layout*), I want it to occupy only the said 30% of screen as well. However because of the way *layout_30* has been defined, the remaining 70% (which are just empty) will also appear in *main_layout*. I don't want that.

So, I tried replacing *layout_30* with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the layout just disappears. It doesn't work.

This is how I am including *layout_30* in *main_layout*:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/layout_30">
</include>
```

Any workarounds?

Note: I'm using *layout_30* only to be included in other layouts (like *main_layout*), not for individual use.

Comment: `include` should work i guess . You should be able to see it in main layout . However for rest of the view you have to assign as Id to `<include>` and align view below it for rest .7 percentage .

Comment: The height of the included *layout_30* will be 100%, instead of the 30% I want. That'll mess up my *main_layout*, and leave the other 70% with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my second solution actually works pretty fine. In *main_layout*, the included *layout_30* shows up nicely, but I can't see anything in the *layout_30* preview, for some reason.